# Why can't i see my tkinter button in the opening window

Tags: python, tkinter

```
ekran= Tk()

ekran.title("132")

ekran.geometry("700x400+200+100")

def deneme():
    print("Merhaba")
yap=Button(
    text="Mesaj",
    command=deneme
)

yap.pack

mainloop()
```

I am learning Python and tkinter library, my teacher wrote these exactly the same but it doesn't work on my Python. Window is opening up but there is no button. Where is the problem?

Comment: `yap.pack` does not call the function.

Answer (score 1):

you have to import tkinter first and also use round bracket like this with.... yap.pack(),, check below this code will work

```
from tkinter import *

ekran = Tk()

ekran.title("132")

ekran.geometry("700x400+200+100")


def deneme():
    print("Merhaba")


yap = Button(text="Mesaj", command=deneme)

yap.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: I didn't notice that i did not share with you guys "from tkinter import *", thank you and sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, i didn't add "()" to my "yap.pack". That was the problem. If there is anyone did the same thing as me, i hope you can solve your problem

Comment: [how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/828183)